# superior "at" vs "in" which preposition to use?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, conversation

(which is the best sentence to use between ( 1 or 2) and (3 or 4) :

1- He is superior at all things. (means he is the best)

2- He is superior in all things.  (means he is the best)

3- He is superior at Math.

4- He is superior in Math.

Comment: Well, to be good (or superior) **at** something. He's better at football than I am.

Comment: @ Lambie Thank you I think I will go with "at"

Comment: Just so you know, this question should probably have been asked on the English Language Learner site rather than here. They will probably move it there. Be well.